# How to do part (i) of the following high-school level problem of vectors?

Tags: vectors

**Question.**

> $ABC$ is a triangle whose vertices have position vectors $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$ respectively, relative to an origin in the plane $ABC$. Show that an arbitrary point $P$ on the segment $AB$ has position vector
> $$\rho\mathbf{a}+\sigma\mathbf{b},$$
> where $\rho\geqslant0$, $\sigma\geqslant0$ and $\rho+\sigma=1$. Give a similar expression for an arbitrary point on the segment $PC$, and deduce that any point inside $ABC$ has position vector
> $$\lambda\mathbf{a}+\mu\mathbf{b}+\nu\mathbf{c},$$
>
> where $\lambda\geqslant0$, $\mu\geqslant0$, $\nu\geqslant0$ and $\lambda+\mu+\nu=1$.
>
> Sketch the region of the plane in which the point $\lambda\mathbf{a}+\mu\mathbf{b}+\nu\mathbf{c}$ lies in each of the following cases:
>
> (i) $\lambda+\mu+\nu=-1$, $\lambda\leqslant0$, $\mu\leqslant0$, $\nu\leqslant0$;
>
> (ii) $\lambda+\mu+\nu=1$, $\mu\leqslant0$, $\nu\leqslant0$.

I am stuck on part (i). Though I can do the rest, I do not think that I fully understand the core concept of this question. I just failed to figure out how to make $\lambda+\mu+\nu=-1$.

---

**My Attempt.** I tried to implement and extend the ideas introduced in the parts before the sketch questions. So for the point on segment AB part, I had $\vec p=(1-\lambda)\vec a+\lambda \vec b$ for $0\le\lambda\le 1$. Then for the point within triangle ABC part (inclusive), I had $(1-\mu)\vec p+\mu \vec c$ for $0\le\mu\le 1$; upon substituting $\vec p$, I had $(1-\mu)(1-\lambda)\vec a+(1-\mu)\lambda\vec b+\mu\vec c$ for which if I add all the vector scalars I would have $1$. I was thinking that maybe I could change the last term $\mu\vec c$ into $-\mu\vec c$ so that the scalars could sum to $-1$, but that would make the region not on the plane ABC. This is as far as I went.

---

**Comment.** I'd rather hear some hint than simply pointing out the way to do it. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The graph is just a triangle with corners $(-1,0,0)$, $(0,-1,0)$, $(0,0,-1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But hmm, I don't think specific coordinates are given in the question... Does it? @DonThousand

Answer (score 1):

A hint for looking at it is to transfer the negative sign from the $\lambda, \mu, \nu$ to $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$. Can you see which region would be represented?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am still confused. If I have negative $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$, would the region be on another symmetric plane about the origin?

Comment: For each vector, assume that it is the normal to a mirror passing through the origin. The take it's reflection through that mirror. Now for the three reflected vectors, they will form a new triangle which is what you're after

Comment: Okay. That was what I thought. I thought I was restricted to the plane which contains points $A,B,C$. My bad. Thanks! @Dhanvi